# Hide generic type prop on export

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a small set of components in which a `Wrapper` is going to manipulate its `children` (therefore referred to as `Component`s by injecting a prop into each of the children via `cloneElement`.
The gotcha here is that `Component` props are of a generic type. When I expose `Component` on the code, I don't want one of its props to be on the signature, because it will be automatically injected by the `Wrapper` component.
I have a concise example which shows what I mean:

`types.ts`

```
export type SomeObject = {
  someKey: string;
};

type PropThatWillBeInjected<T extends SomeObject> = {
  fn: (value: string) => T;
};

export type WannaBePropTypes = {
  name: string;
};

export type PropTypes<T extends SomeObject> = PropThatWillBeInjected<T> &
  WannaBePropTypes;
```

Important: `PropTypes<T>` is what `Component` expects, but as a programmer, I want `WannaBePropTypes` to be the signature of this component.
Moving on...

`Component.tsx`

```
function Component<T extends SomeObject>(props: PropTypes<T>) {
  const { fn, name } = props;
  const result = fn(name);
  return <div>Hello, {result.someKey}</div>;
}

export default Component;
```

`Wrapper.tsx`

```
function Wrapper(props: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      {React.Children.map(
        children as ReactElement<PropTypes<SomeObject>>,
        (child, index) =>
          cloneElement(child, {
            ...child.props,
            fn: (value: string) => ({
              someKey: `${value}-${index}`,
            }),
          })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wrapper;
```

As expected, when I try to use these components as the following, the code works but the compiler complains:

```
<Wrapper>
  <Component name="Alice" />
  <Component name="Bob" />
</Wrapper>
```

> Property 'fn' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'PropThatWillBeInjected'.(2741)

---

Is there a way to cast `Component` so I don't need to pass `fn` manually? I know there's a way when the prop types is not generic...

What I've tried:

1. Making `fn` optional: works, but this is not the solution I'm looking for;
2. Wrapping `Component` with another component and passing a `noop` to `Component`: works, but I don't want to create this unnecessary wrapper;

A playground with this sample code: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3r2xuf?file=App.tsx)

Comment: The problem you are describing sounds unusual. Perhaps if you explain the root cause of the issue, there may be a simpler way to solve it, such as using a higher-order component (HOC). With the information you have provided, I do not see a way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @FlatGlobe a HOC is something I'm trying to avoid (pretty much what I mentioned in Try #2). This is something I want to tackle with Typescript only. I've provided a sample code link reproducing the scenario I'm dealing with. What other information should I add?

Comment: I believe one other way to look into my question is answering: given that I want to export a component, how do I export it as a different type (this type being generic)? For instance, `export default Component as SomeType<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I inderstand your problem correctly, you want to call `Component` as `<Component name="Alice" />` and there should be some internal logic for two cases: when `fn` was passed and when not. If so, you can create unnecessary type (instead of unnecessary wrapper) which will be one of `WannaBePropTypes` or full props. This is like some combination of your try#1 and try#2:

```
type FullProps<T extends SomeObject> = PropThatWillBeInjected<T> & WannaBePropTypes;

type PropTypes<T extends SomeObject> = FullProps<T> | WannaBePropTypes;
```

So `fn` is optional until you define `children as ReactElement<FullProps<SomeObject>>` in `Wrapper` component.
As for the `Component`, I think you can just cast props to `FullProps`:

```
const { fn, name } = props as FullProps<T>;
```

But if you need more strict code for some reason, you can narrow `props` type this way:

```
function isFullProps<T extends SomeObject>(props: PropTypes<T>): props is FullProps<T> {
    return !!(props as FullProps<T>).fn;
}

function Component<T extends SomeObject>(props: PropTypes<T>) {
    if (!isFullProps(props)) return <></>;
    const { fn, name } = props;
    const result = fn(name);
    return <div>Hello, {result.someKey}</div>;
}
```

Though it seems this condition will always be false in your case.
This is how *to tackle with Typescript only*.

BTW: maybe you can just pass array of `WannaBePropTypes` objects into `Wrapper` instead of children? This sounds better if `<Component name="Alice" />` should do nothing by itself.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide the code for `Component`? At first glance, this doesn't seem to solve the issue, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Added some things. Hope this will help

Comment: This indeed helped! Having `FullProps` and `PropTypes` did the trick. Thank you very much, @Rus